# adding an angular animation to a host element

Tags: angular, animation, angular-animations

i added an animation to the host via

```
@Component({
   ....,
   animations: [
      trigger('slideIn', [
          ...
      ])
   ],
   host: {
      '[@animation]': 'condition'
   }
}
```

which worked well, on compilation i was told this is deprecated and i should use @HostBinding ...

```
@HostBinding('[@animation]') get slideIn() {
   return condition;
}
```

which throws me an error

```
Can't bind to '[@animation' since it isn't a known property of 'my-component-selector'.
```

but i cannot add an animation into my module.. what can i do ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The square brackets are not necessary with `@HostBinding()`

```ts
@HostBinding('@slideIn') get slideIn() {
```

There are two decorators `@HostBinding()` and `@HostListener()` therefore the distinction between `()` and `[]` isn't necessary, while it is when `host: [...]` is used.

Answer (score 16):

I'm writing this answer because I struggled a little bit with the syntax and I like examples for dummies, but Günter's answer is correct.

What I had to do:

```js
    @Component({
        selector: 'app-sidenav',
        templateUrl: './sidenav.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./sidenav.component.scss'],
        animations: [
            trigger('toggleDrawer', [
                state('closed', style({
                    transform: 'translateX(0)',
                    'box-shadow': '0px 3px 6px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)'
                })),
                state('opened', style({
                    transform: 'translateX(80vw)'
                })),
                transition('closed <=> opened', animate(300))
            ])
        ]
    })
    export class SidenavComponent implements OnInit {

        private state: 'opened' | 'closed' = 'closed';

        // binds the animation to the host component
        @HostBinding('@toggleDrawer') get getToggleDrawer(): string {
            return this.state === 'closed' ? 'opened' : 'closed';
        }

        constructor() { }

        ngOnInit(): void {
        }

        // toggle drawer
        toggle(): void {
            this.state = this.state === 'closed' ? 'opened' : 'closed';
        }

        // opens drawer
        open(): void {
            this.state = 'opened';
        }

        // closes drawer
        close(): void {
            this.state = 'closed';
        }

    }
```

Comment: Anyone knows, how to bind an `(@toggleDrawer.done)` (callback on animation end) to the host?

Comment: @FrankNocke Have you tried `@HostListener('@toggleDrawer.done', ['$event'])` ? Might work.

Comment: @tinnick wow, it's really working like this!   `@HostListener('@transformPanel.done', ['$event'])` thank you!